# Where can I find suttas about the immaterial realm?

Tags: nirvana, jhana, tipitaka

I read in Ajahn Brahms book that you pass through 4 immaterial realms after jhanas and before enlightenment. I want to know more about them. Where  can I find the suttas in the Tripitaka?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immaterial jhana are optional & not required for enlightenment (refer to [SN 12.70](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.070.than.html)), which is why immaterial jhana are not included in the noble eightfold path (refer to [SN 45.8](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn45/sn45.008.than.html)). The Buddha attained enlightenment by developing the 4th material jhana (refer to [MN 19](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.019.than.html)). However, the immaterial jhana are described in many suttas (such as in detail in [MN 111](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.111.than.html)) because they are a natural development of concentration or quieting (refer to [SN 36.10](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn36/sn36.011.than.html)). I recommend reading [MN 111](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.111.than.html).